# Sharepoint 2010 project - disable caching

Tags: caching, sharepoint-2010

I have a small SharePoint project which integrates into a larger SharePoint project. My project has several javascript files and images (via CSS). Whenever I update the app (javascript or images or both), I need to explicitly do a Ctrl + F5 (force refresh) to get the latest version. Users are seeing old data as it is being cached. This application is being used by hundreds of users and I can't tell everyone of them to do a Ctrl + F5.

How do I disable caching *completely* for my project?

Comment: Where are you referencing your scripts?  Are they added in code for user controls or are they script tags on .aspx pages?

Comment: They are in script tags on ASPX pages.

Comment: One last thing.  You should retag your question to include [sharepoint].  There are much more questions tagged with that and it would increase your chances of getting other responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a server/user control for script/image/css references that wraps the actual html.  The control would add a random query string to each of your script/css/image references every time a user requests the page.  Your reference would be like:

> /_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/Menu.css?rev={insert random guid}

This would cause the browser to reload the file each time.

However, why would you want to remove caching as that improves load time of pages for your users?  You could just as easily use the example that I have and instead of generating a random guid it would generate a guid based on a hash of the current file.  That way it would only force the user to update the file if it actually changed.  Or, even better, SharePoint already has the `SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl` which you can use to create a url that will be cached correctly.  Here is an example

Html in master page (RelativeUrl is under "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS")

```
<MyControls:CacheSafeScriptLinkControl RelativeUrl="MyFeature/js/core.js" 
  runat="server" />
```

Server Control

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
  string cacheSafeUrl = 
    SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl(RelativeUrl, false);

  ScriptLink scriptLink = new ScriptLink
  {
    Language = "javascript",
    Localizable = false,
    Name = cacheSafeUrl,
    Version = 4
  };

  Controls.Add(scriptLink);

  base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

Comment: I want to remove caching because sometimes users are seeing an outdated version of my files (javascript, images). Is there any other way to disable caching without appending a random string to the URL?

Comment: If you use the SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl to generate your urls then you would only have to recycle the app pools in order to avoid your users having to see outdated file versions.  The only other option I know is to turn off caching for certain file extensions on the Web Application in IIS.  You can do that using output caching and cache rules.

Comment: Thanks for the example user control. I'll also look into `SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl`.

Comment: No problem.  If you want more info on the issue then read this blog entry by Chris O'Brien (http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/11/avoiding-bugs-from-cached-javascript.html).  I derived my solution from that article.